# How to use timer function to get the data between some time duration?

Tags: javascript, typescript, timer

When temperature increases by 1 degree, I just need to take the data from the last 30 seconds from my machine and send it to my DB. Am I missing anything?

```
set interval(function x(){
If(current_temp != prev_temp){
    if((current_temp-prev_temp)>1 || (current_temp - prev_temp)<1){  
       Console.log('send data to end point egress ');
    }
    console.log('send id to the end point');
  }
}),30000)
```

Comment: that is setInterval not set interval

Comment: change `setInterval` instead of `set interval` .JavaScript case sensitive .And also change `first` `If` with lowercase `if`

Comment: ya Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your typos, and initialized the variables.

```
var current_temp = 20;
var prev_temp = 18;
setInterval(function(){
    if(current_temp !== prev_temp){
        if((current_temp - prev_temp) > 1 || (current_temp - prev_temp) < 1){  
            console.log('send data to end point egress');
    }
    console.log('send id to the end point');
  }
}, 3000);
```

Although if you want to check if the temperature changed by 1 degree you should use something like this:

```
var prev_temp = 50;
var current_temp = null;
setInterval(function(){
    current_temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1); // generate random number between 1 - 100
    if((current_temp - prev_temp) === 1){ // send data only when the difference is 1 ??
        console.log('send data to end point egress');
  }
    console.log('send id to the end point');
  prev_temp = current_temp; // update previous temperature with the current one
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your logic,but here i need to check temp first then should go into the loop. because after temp increase only i can take last 30 sec data.